# Replacement for jQuery method $.browser (To identify the Browser name) in jQuery version 2.1.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery-1.4.1.js library in my MVC 3 application.Here i am using $.browser to 
  make a check for browser name.And it gives me the browser name. Now i am migrating my 
  application to use jQuery-2.1.1.js. Here in this jQuery latest version,this jQuery method
  $.browser gives me "Undefined",instead of giving me the browser name. Do we have any 
  replacement jQuery method to identify the browser in jQuery version 2.1.1, any help
  would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you want to know how to override  jquery functions ?

Answer (score 1):

[From jquery documentation:](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)
Description: Contains flags for the useragent, read from navigator.userAgent. This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead.

So you have 2 options, along with jquery 2.1.1 use a migration script read [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme).

or remove use of $.browser, and use feature detection as recommended. [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#s2) is good start point.

Answer (score 0):

The .browser call has been removed in jquery 1.9
have a look at http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/ for more details.

I placed the following html in my code and this cleared up the $.browser error

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps u